# How to simplify this long notebook?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, interpolation

I have some large calculations I want to simplify them to reduce the number of lines as well as saving time.

I have a quadratic equation based on C and I want its delta==0 and then solve it for "Ti".

So here is the code:

```
c2 = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "3.290858073703381"}], "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "19"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["Te", 
RowBox[{"7", "/", "2"}]]}],
"MathMLPresentationTag",
AutoDelete->True]\);

b2 = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"6.551670446021406", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"6.325736879169076", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "14"], "Te"}], "+", 
RowBox[{"4.156912806311107", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "14"], "Ti"}]}], ")"}], 
RowBox[{"3", "/", "2"}]]}], 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"1.5217391304347827", "Te"}], "+", "Ti"}]]}],
"MathMLPresentationTag",
AutoDelete->True]\)

a2 = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{
FractionBox["1", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"1.5217391304347827", "Te"}], "+", "Ti"}], ")"}], "2"]], 
      "6.359168241965974", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1.326234200936648"}], "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "16"], " ", 
SqrtBox["Te"], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"1.708371825471698", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "8"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"261121.0000000001", "Te"}], "+", 
RowBox[{"71403.31854503311", 
SuperscriptBox["Te", "1.34"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"562.1000000000001", 
SuperscriptBox["Te", "2"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"1.", 
SuperscriptBox["Te", "3"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.055296744400476106", 
SuperscriptBox["Te", "3.5"]}]}], ")"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"9.630927115492518", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "30"], 
SuperscriptBox["E", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "53.423654461591696"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"1", "+", 
RowBox[{"Ti", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0.18401", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0.00086544", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.000006833", "Ti"}]}], ")"}], " ", "Ti"}]}], ")"}]}]}], 
RowBox[{"Ti", "+", 
RowBox[{"0.13240000000000002", 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "2"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0012499", 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0000011615", 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "4"]}]}]], ")"}], 
RowBox[{"1", "/", "3"}]]}]], " ", "Ti", " ", 
SqrtBox[
FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"1", "+", 
RowBox[{"Ti", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0.18401", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0.00086544", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.000006833", "Ti"}]}], ")"}], " ", "Ti"}]}], ")"}]}]}], 
RowBox[{"Ti", "+", 
RowBox[{"0.13240000000000002", 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "2"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0012499", 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0000011615", 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "4"]}]}]], ")"}], 
RowBox[{"1", "/", "3"}]], 
SuperscriptBox["Ti", "3"]]], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"860955.6607834697", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"Ti", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"113990.5294877314", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"Ti", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1076.1084804132586", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"1.", "Ti"}]}], ")"}]}]}], ")"}]}]}], ")"}]}], ")"}], "/", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"146348.60237084737", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"Ti", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"26929.606322259624", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"Ti", " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"126.65593443582614", 
StyleBox[" ", "Text"], "+", 
RowBox[{"1.", "Ti"}]}], ")"}]}]}], ")"}]}]}], ")"}]}]}], ")"}]}],
"MathMLPresentationTag",
AutoDelete->True]\);


eq2 = a2*C^2 + b2*C + c2
```

The important thing is Te, and Ti are connected to each other through this data I've interpolated, and it should be entered in the calculations, I'm not sure if the way I've done is correct:

```
Te1 = {48.99113713485949`, 57.15602646599817`, 63.79147627994348`, 
   68.72654253489631`, 72.10867597844171`, 74.27488841414075`, 
   75.59850571844034`, 76.39719701728971`, 76.90492714760401`, 
   77.27902617318777`, 77.61857440396297`, 77.98242783750561`, 
   78.40319202934029`, 78.8969759602128`, 79.4698325203875`, 
   80.12187645443619`, 80.84986348233821`, 81.64878035472607`, 
   82.51281001072049`, 83.43590600788585`, 84.41212445892737`, 
   85.4358065497098`, 86.50166983334209`, 87.6048445949681`, 
   88.74087786862594`, 89.90571910418059`, 91.09569610709454`, 
   92.30748650609614`, 93.53808789476548`, 94.78478847511681`, 
   96.04513921163446`, 97.3169279989868`, 98.59815603981738`, 
   99.88701644722977`, 101.18187498326719`, 102.48125279025743`, 
   103.78381094752551`, 105.08833667970659`, 106.39373104715428`, 
   107.698997958974`, 109.00323436206051`, 110.30562147336501`, 
   111.60541693640624`, 112.90194779615074`, 114.19460419850998`, 
   115.4828337317164`};


Ti = Table[Ti, {Ti, 50, 500, 10}];

data = Transpose[{Ti, Te1}];

x2 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Te := x2[Ti];  (*Interpolate Te for the given Ti values*)
```

after that, I solved delta==0 for that:

```
FindRootb2^2-4a2*c2 == 0, {Ti, 117}]
```

now we can find **C** which is -b2/2a2

C=-300.97

At this stage I want to Solve another equation and then plot it.
This equation should be solved for H and H-Ti should be plotted.

```
equation=300.97 + 0.396552 H (1.52174 Te + Ti)
```

Traditionally, I simply wrote solve for each 46 components I had, which is not professional, then ListLinePlot that.

```
Solve[equation[[1]] == 0, H] ...... to      Solve[equation[[46]] == 0, H]
```

now how can this notebook be written in a better way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be through use of sections and to maintain one statement per cell.

This combination helps you focus on the important stuff and thus simplifies debugging.

You can also use semi-colons to suppress intermediate output.

Comments (as text cells) help as well.

The [computational essay](https://notebookarchive.org/collection-pod?collection=computational-essays) metaphor may help.